# What are the continuous automorphisms of $\Bbb T$?

Tags: proof-verification, locally-compact-groups, continuous-homomorphisms

I wanted to check my reasoning on this problem. From standard Pontrjagin duality arguments, it's not hard to see that the continuous *homomorphisms* of the torus (to itself) are nothing more than the maps $z\mapsto z^n$ where $n\in\Bbb Z$. If $n\neq \pm 1$, these maps are clearly not bijective since we have multiple $n$th roots. If $n=0$, this gives rise to the trivial homomorphism which is definitely not bijective. This leaves us with $n=\pm 1$. If $n=1$, then this is clearly an automorphism. It's also not hard to see that $n=-1$ corresponds to an automorphism. Is my logic sound? Is the automorphism group of $\Bbb T$ composed of nothing more than the functions $z\mapsto z$ and $z\mapsto z^{-1}$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. (Pontryagin duality tells you this as well.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks! I thought so but needed someone to verify that I wasn't incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The continuous automorphisms are simply $z\mapsto z$ and $z\mapsto z^{-1}$ as stated in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Ah I just asked the same question because I didn't find this one until it was pointed out to me.  But I was looking for an elementary proof.  So I posted one there, if you care the link is here:
 [How to prove the group of automorphisms of $S^1$ as a topological group is $\mathbb Z_2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249048/how-to-prove-the-group-of-automorphisms-of-s1-as-a-topological-group-is-mat?noredirect=1#comment2539130_1249048)

Comment: I'm the one that linked the question to you :P I think there's a more elementary way to prove it than what you did, but it requires viewing $\Bbb T$ as $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ and doing a similar argument as is done in deriving the continuous characters of $\Bbb R$.