# group of automorphisms of the circle

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I think I misunderstand something about the definition of a homeomorphism of a topological space. We know an automorphism of a topological space $X$ is a homeomorphism from $X$ to itself. So it should be bijective and continuous with a continuous inverse. Now, my understanding is that every rotation of the circle is a homeomorphism of the circle. But in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1249048/1061870), the OP says that the automorphism group of $S^1$ as a topological group is $\mathbb{Z}_2$. What is wrong with my conclusion? Do rotations leave the group stucture of the circle unchanged?

Comment: The key is "topological group." If you think of the circle as a group, then rotations don't preserve the identity, so are not *group* automorphisms.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Thanks! But if we want to forget the group structure, rotations are homeomorphisms of the circle. So they are also automorphisms of $S^1$ as a topological space. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes. Rotations are topological automorphisms.